# Understanding "Error in ggplot(data = penguins) : object 'penguins' not found"

Tags: r

```
> install.packages("palmerpenguins")
Installing package into ‘/cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://rspm/default/__linux__/focal/latest/src/contrib/palmerpenguins_0.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3001167 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *binary* package ‘palmerpenguins’ ...
* DONE (palmerpenguins)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmphP3P09/downloaded_packages’
> library(palmerpenguins)
> ggplot(data=penguins) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g, color=species))
Error in ggplot(data = penguins) : could not find function "ggplot"
> install.packages(ggplot)
Error in install.packages : object 'ggplot' not found
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

> install.packages("ggplot2")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

> install.packages("ggplot2")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

> install.packages("ggplot2")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘/cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://rspm/default/__linux__/focal/latest/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4203322 bytes (4.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.0 MB

* installing *binary* package ‘ggplot2’ ...
* DONE (ggplot2)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpesapFQ/downloaded_packages’
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(data=penguins) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g, color=g))
Error in ggplot(data = penguins) : object 'penguins' not found
```

**trial**:

```
ggplot(data=penguins) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g, color=g))
```

to generate scatter plot. But I am facing following error everytime.
**error**:

```
Error in ggplot(data = penguins) : object 'penguins' not found
```

**Help**: Please rectify exactly what should I correct in the code.
thanks

Comment: Your r session seems to have restarted multiple times. Be sure to run `library(palmerpenguins)` after the last restart and before you draw the plot.

Comment: You only need to run `install.packages(xyx)` once, then afterwards load the package using `library(xyz)`. You also can load the `penguins` data without loading the package with `data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")`

Comment: Please choose a title which actually describes your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to ggplot it, without data (The data is missing). The colors vector you did not create.
Be sure to load the ggplot2 package too

```
# Load the packages
library(ggplot2)
library(palmerpenguins) 

data(penguins) # Load the data

ggplot(data=penguins) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g))
```

Comment: The line `data(penguins)` is unnecessary for data sets that are lazy loaded by packages such as `palmerpenguins`. As long as the library is loaded, `penguins` is available. You only have to use `data()` for old-style datasets which aren't really used much anymore.